Combine SQL queries for output
I have two queries, where I need to get the ID from the first query and pass it to the second query.
How do I do this for all the ID's in the first query?
select id, name from [ignite].[COND]  --> ID needed for second query

select cm.name as "Machine Name"
from [ignite].[COND] c, [ignite].[CONM_id] cm, [ignite].[CONSW_id]sw --> ID from previous query.
where c.id = 'id'
and cm.id = sw.pwmy
group by cm.name
order by sum(sw.qp) desc


Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. There are lots of ways of doing this e.g. CTEs or subqueries

Have you ever heard of JOIN?

This can be solved by using a join. On many platforms there are other options also available. After the from using an inline view like:
from ( query )

and then join the current list of tables such as:
from ( query ) t0
join t1
on   ...
join t2
on   ...

It is recommended to use explicit join style instead of Oracle-style; in almost all scenarios this yields more readable queries, easier detection of missing optional joins and better performance.
